# Generate a SHA256 hex String from List of Strings in Java that can be checked with sha256sum CLI command?

Tags: java, linux, serialization, hash, sha256

I have a `List<String>` that I wish to display SHA-256 of that `List<String>` content and then write to the File. Then I wish to control the SHA-256 produced by Java and SHA-256 produced by Linux CLI `sha256sum file.txt`.

I first start with a Serializing of the `List<String> list`:

```
byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) list);
```

and producing a method to perform SHA-256:

```
public static BiFunction<byte[], String, String> stringDigestFromBytes =
        (h, t) -> Hex.encodeHexString(DigestUtils.getDigest(t).digest(h));
```

Then, before writing `list` to the file I produce Java SHA-256:

```
String hex256 = stringDigestFromBytes.apply(bytes, "SHA-256");
```

And then write `list` to the file:

```
Files.write(Path.of("file.txt"), list);
```

However that Java SHA-256 doesn't match the SHA-256 produced with Linux CLI `sha256sum file.txt`. Any ideas on how to make it possible that both SHA-256 are the same?

Comment: Quite a lot of ops going on there, some quite likely redundant. Wouldn't it be better (since it's `List<String>`) just to take the SHA256 sum of the strings *as a text file*? It really depends on your motivation

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the serialization of `list` using `SerializationUtils.serialize` produces the same result as just concatenating the UTF-8 encodings of each string in `list`? I wouldn't think so, but I'm not familiar with `SerializationUtils.serialize`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using the Apache DigestUtils class then use:

```
String hex256 = new DigestUtils(MessageDigestAlgorithms.SHA_256)
    .digestAsHex(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following produces the same hash as `sha256sum` does on a text file containing the same strings:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HexFormat;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Hash256 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> strings = List.of("alpha", "beta", "gamma");
            final String SEP = "\n";
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            String originalString = strings.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(SEP));
            originalString += SEP;
            byte[] encodedHash = digest.digest(originalString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            System.out.println(HexFormat.of().formatHex(encodedHash));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```